# What's the mistake in my Python version of a toy SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm currently going through Andrej Karpathy's [Hacker's guide to Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/neuralnets/). In *Chapter 2: Machine Learning, Binary Classification*, he gives an example of a (very basic) SVM. Here's Karpathy's code:

```
var a = 1, b = -2, c = -1; // initial parameters
for(var iter = 0; iter < 400; iter++) {
  // pick a random data point
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  var x = data[i][0];
  var y = data[i][1];
  var label = labels[i];

// compute pull
  var score = a*x + b*y + c;
  var pull = 0.0;
  if(label === 1 && score < 1) pull = 1;
  if(label === -1 && score > -1) pull = -1;

// compute gradient and update parameters
  var step_size = 0.01;
  a += step_size * (x * pull - a); // -a is from the regularization
  b += step_size * (y * pull - b); // -b is from the regularization
  c += step_size * (1 * pull);
}
```

And the following is my version, in Python:

```
import numpy
import random

X = numpy.array([[1.2, 0.7],
                 [-0.3, 0.5],
                 [-3, -1],
                 [0.1, 1.0],
                 [3.0, 1.1],
                 [2.1, -3]])

labels = [1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1]

a = 1
b = -2
c = -1

l = len(X)-1

steps = 400

for n in range(0, steps):
    i = random.randint(0, l)
    x = X[i][0]
    y = X[i][1]
    label = labels[i]

    if n == 0:
            for j in range(0, l+1):
                x = X[j][0]
                y = X[j][1]
                label = labels[j]
                score = a*x + b*y + c
                print x,",",y,"-->", label, "vs.", score

    score = a*x + b*y + c
    pull = 0.0
    if label == 1 and score < 1:
        pull = 1
    if label == -1 and score > -1:
        pull = -1

    step_size = 0.01
    a += step_size * (x * pull - a)
    b += step_size * (y * pull - b)
    c += step_size * (1 * pull)

    if n == steps-1:
        print ""
        for j in range(0, l+1):
            x = X[j][0]
            y = X[j][1]
            label = labels[j]
            score = a*x + b*y + c
            print x,",",y,"-->", label, "vs.", score
```

The problem is, that even after more than the suggested 400 iterations, for some of the vectors, the parameters don't yield the correct label.

Here's the output after 400 iterations:

```
1.2 , 0.7 --> 1 vs. -0.939483353298
-0.3 , 0.5 --> -1 vs. -0.589208602761
-3.0 , -1.0 --> 1 vs. 0.651953448705
0.1 , 1.0 --> -1 vs. -0.921882586141
3.0 , 1.1 --> -1 vs. -1.44552077331
2.1 , -3.0 --> 1 vs. 0.896623596303
```

The first value after the "-->" is the correct label, second value is the score, i.e. learned label.

All vector/learned labels are correct (in the sense of being assigned a value with the correct sign), except for the first one.

I'm not sure what the reason is for this: Did I make a mistake in my code? I checked it a few times, but didn't find anything. Or am I forgetting something Python specific here. Or, finally, is there some ML related reason why the correct label isn't learned in this case. Doubt it though, otherwise it doesn't make sense that Karpathy got the right results.

Any comments or help in figuring it out much appreciated.

Comment: I'm familiar with neural nets, but not SVM specifically. My question to you is: are you sure it is incorrect? After giving it your dataset and 400 iterations of learning, it has come up with the best a,b,c values that it can to approximate all of the results. However, it may be that this type of model is not enough expressive enough to get them all correct. In a backprop network I might consider adding hidden nodes for example. I don't know how to recommend to specifically modify this SVM structure, but I may think about it.

Comment: I'm no expert either, but SVMs are usually solved in the dual form (Lagrange multipliers). I've rarely seen it done this way and I'm not sure how this simple unconstrained gradient descent is supposed to solve the constrained primal problem... see for example http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf

Comment: I haven't stepped through the code (yet), but I can perhaps help a little.
First, gradient descent is one way that SVM algorithms find the brane that provides the best classification, especially when the sets are not well connected.  Second, linear classifiers can have strange properties when confronted with data sets that don't divide cleanly.  I'm quite accustomed to having some of my data set mis-classified.  If I've plotted your data properly, there's no line to separate the two sets.
Did you run the original code, too?  Output with learned values?

Comment: As far as I can tell your code should be identical to the provided code. So I'm guessing this is just the way it works with that particular dataset.

Comment: @RobertB Apologies for the delayed answer. My assumption that it is wrong is due to the tutorial states that the same data set /is/ completely learned by the provided code. So my first question was, is my code wrong. As your write below, it seems the code is right, but it's a learning problem after all maybe.

Comment: Correction to my above comment: As pointed out in the answer by @Prune I used a different data set than the one used by Karpathy in the final step of the development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that I found the problem(s):

(A) Your data set has no linear cut.

(B) Karpathy's "Monte Carlo" gradient descent thrashes on such a data set.

(C) You and Karpathy used different data.

```
DATA SETS
label   Karpathy's      yours
  1     [1.2, 0.7]      [1.2, 0.7]
 -1     [-0.3, -0.5]    [-0.3, 0.5]
  1     [3.0, 0.1]      [-3, -1]
 -1     [-0.1, -1.0]    [0.1, 1.0]
 -1     [-1.0, 1.1]     [3.0, 1.1]
  1     [2.1, -3]       [2.1, -3]
```

The data set you gave almost has a cut line (hyperplane) at roughly 
y = 1/3x + 1/2, but the three points closets to the line argue constantly about the division.  As it turns out, the best divider is distinctly different, leaving [1.2, 0.7] seriously on the wrong side of the line, but quite unhappy about that.

The original data has a neat cut line at roughly y = -3x + 1, which this algorithm roughly approximates with (rounded) 0.6x - 0.1y - 0.5

Again, this algorithm is looking for a minimal-cost fit rather than the "pure" SVM of the widest separating channel.  Even when there *is* a neat cut line, this algorithm does nto converge on it; rather, it hacks its way to the general vicinity of an acceptable solution.

It chooses a random point.  If the point is solidly classified -- the score is of the right sign with a magnitude > 1 -- nothing happens.  However, if the point is on the wrong side of the line, or even too close for comfort, then it pulls the parameters for more favourable treatment.

Unless the channel is 2 units wide, the points within the disputed territories will continue to take turns shoving it back and forth.  There is no convergence criterion ... and, indeed, no convergence guarantee after a certain point.

Look carefully at Karpathy's code: the main algorithm makes changes for data points with scores < 1 or > -1 (depending on training class).  However, the evaluation algorithm claims victory if the sign of the result is correct.  This is reasonable, but it isn't entirely consistent with the training function.  In my trials, that first point always has a score with magnitude < 0.07, but the actual value waffles on either side of 0.  The other points are well clear of 0, but only two of them pass 1.  There are four points arguing over where the line should be.

---

Does this clear things up for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extremely detailed answer. I have some important deadline tomorrow, so I'll only get a chance to really look at your answer to see if I understand it in a day or two from now. For now, I'll vote up, will get back to it in a bit (and will mark as answered then as well).

Comment: Alright, first remark: Absolutely failed to see I use the wrong data set. A bit above the actual data you found, Karpathy lists another data set (right under the begging of the chapter Binary Classification), which is the one I used. The two seem mostly identical, and I wonder now if perhaps the first data set led to the problem I found, which is why he changed a few values for the later development (and then forgot to correct the first set). Still trying to understand /why/ it doesn't work (which means I need to look up what linear cut means formally)

Comment: I'm simplifying the terminology.  By "linear cut", I mean that the data has a perfect, straight dividing line: you can draw a line that has *all* of the +1 data on one side, and all of the -1 data on the other side.  Simple SVMs all work with linear dividers, but some implementations allow for polynomial and Gaussian partitions.  LibSVM (raw) and the TrustedAnalytics wrapper thereof are good if you want to play with that level (I'm on the TAP team).

Comment: I sort of imagined it like that, but still lack a lot of intuition. This is really my first dive into ML. I have a few more questions if you allow, thought I'm not sure if I should open a new questions or not.

(1) A conceptual question: e.g. for some data point [1, -1] with correct label -1, I am allowed to think of it as a 3d coordinate, i.e. [1, -1, -1], right? Such that for all data points, the z coordinate is the label. And then the "linear cut" is a (2d) plane that (ideally) separates all point/label triples. Right so far? (1/3)

Comment: (2) Next, in case of different algorithms (using polynomials?), these separating shapes can be more complex, and are able to separate data sets that cannot be divided just by a "flat" plane, correct?

(3) Back to the tutorial code/data set: I ran my Python code with the correct data, but it *still* doesn't give good results. The first value [1.2, 0.7] with label 1.0, is now approximated close to 0, but still, half of the runs to 400, the learned sign is negative. Any idea why? (2/3)

Comment: (4) Finally: I'd like to look at the data myself, to really see how it can (or cannot) be divided linearly, but I don't know what program to use. Would you say Octave is an option for someone who's just starting to learn (and visualize) data approaches? (3/3)

Comment: This is a good insight for the first step of the Gaussian "kernel trick" (save that thought for much later).  I don't think it's the right insight for what you're doing.  Yes, you should open more questions.  However, remember to keep them code-based if you're posting in StackOverflow: this site has a programming-problem focus; theoretical questions go elsewhere in the StackExchange network.

Comment: The only real problem with your visualization is that that linear cut is ex-post-facto reasoning.  Instead, we're looking for something that cuts the x-y plane, such that we can compute z as a simple step function of that line.  For instance, the (later) Karpahty data set has a nice cut line at roughly x=0.6.  It's not the absolute best fit, but it does the job.

Comment: (2) Correct.  That "kernel trick" I mentioned is merely a transformation function.

Comment: (3) I explained this in my detailed answer.  Karpathy's algorithm doesn't work well on data with points close to the dividing line: they argue about the line's position, and their argument is based on a best-fit distance, rather than merely being satisfied with a clean cut.

Comment: (4) I used the Eberhard-Faber-Hammermill display hardware (pencil & paper).  It's only 6 points.  If you want to display things programmatically, Octave and MatPlotLib are good choices.

Comment: re (3): Sorry for missing this due to sloppy reading. And great answer to (4). Thanks again!